# (Agora, iOS, Swift) Example Code Issue for ScreenShare - It shares camera instead of screen

Tags: swift, live-streaming, agora.io, screensharing, agora-web-sdk-ng

I've successfully ran and built the ScreenShare example code written by Agora:
https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/tree/master/iOS/APIExample/Examples/Advanced/ScreenShare

However, when I use the app and use the ScreenShare functionality, it shares my front-view camera instead of my screen. I've verified this by connecting to the same AppId and Channel here:
https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-websdk-api-example-4.x/shareTheScreen/index.html

Does anyone know what the issue is? I'm not sure sure why the example code isn't working as intended.

Things I've tried:

- Verified Broadcast Extension is running once RPSystemBroadcastPickerView is clicked.

Suspected Fix:

- Use a method for AgoraRtcEngine to change Video Source to Screen. (Not sure how)

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Need to change to in AgoraUploader.swift:

sharedAgoraEngine.joinChannel(byToken: KeyCenter.Token, channelId: channel, info: nil, uid: SCREEN_SHARE_UID, joinSuccess: nil)